# koa js async await not working when used with ajax and promise

Tags: koa

I'm using koa as a rest backend but I can't get the routing and request/response to work properly, when the URL is called using axios the promise is failing.

server.js

```
const route = require('koa-route');
const serve = require('koa-static');
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser');
const Datastore = require('nedb'),
      db = new Datastore({
          filename: __dirname +'/storage.db' ,
          autoload: true
      });
// something 
app.use(bodyParser());

app.use(serve(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.use(route.get('/api/projects', async function (next) {
    let projects = [];
    await db.find({}, function (err, docs) {
        projects = docs;
    });

    this.body = projects;
}));

const PORT = process.argv[2] || process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(3000);
```

when I make a request to /api/projects using axios I get and empty array

from my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js --exec babel-node --presets es2015,stage-2"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing promises with callbacks, which is most likely causing your problems.

Stick to using promises:

```
app.use(route.get('/api/projects', async function (next) {
  let projects = await db.find({});
  this.body = projects;
}));
```

Comment: nedb doesn't quit support that structure, I've updated the code but now Im getting Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.props.project.map is not a function as an error

Comment: If it doesn't support promises, you can't (directly) use `await`. You need something like [`nedb-promise`](https://github.com/jrop/nedb-promise) to wrap the NeDB methods with promises.